# Can I Mix Laravel With Vue-storefront Template

Tags: vue.js, laravel-mix, vue-storefront

Is it possible if I mix Laravel 5.7 with this vue template : 
https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue Storefront is not a template. It's a eCommerce framework with it's own API and database (see this architecture diagram).

If your question is about using Vue Storefront with your custom Laravel backend then it's doable. VS is meant to be backend agnostic which means it can work with any backend if you provide appropiate connector. https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront-integration-boilerplate - here you can find integration boilerplate. There are few more resources on this topic in VS readme.

Also in case of any problems feel free to ask on community slack https://join.slack.com/t/vuestorefront/shared_invite/enQtMzA4MTM2NTE5NjM2LTI1M2RmOWIyOTk0MzFlMDU3YzJlYzcyYzNiNjUyZWJiMTZjZjc3MjRlYmE5ZWQ1YWRhNTQyM2ZjN2ZkMzZlNTg

Comment: Hi @Filip, I'm trying to use vue storefront but one issue is that I cant access admin panel. I means if it is a complete framework there should be some views from where I can add or modify products. How can I use CRUD operations as admin and also things like entertaining orders

Comment: @AsimKhan Actually Vue Storefront is the Headless eCommerce frontend platform. So, You can't do it like admin task.